# Error when using predict() with randomForest in R

Tags: r, prediction, random-forest

I'm trying to predict the class of four Data Deficient species using the predict() function in randomForest. I've run RF on my original data and created a RF object, and I then want to use this to predict the class of the new data.

The code I am using is:

```
# original data set "procellminvar" 
# DD sp only "procelldd"

#run RF on original data set

    procellminvar$current.red.list<-factor(procellminvar$current.red.list)
    procell6<-procellminvar[,6:80]
    procell6.imputed<-rfImpute(current.red.list~.,procell6)
    procellminvar.rf<-randomForest(current.red.list~., procell6.imputed, votes=true, importance=TRUE, ntree=1000)
    round(importance(procellminvar.rf),2)

#run prediction using original data and new data (DD sp only)

    predict(procellminvar.rf, procelldd)
```

The RF runs fine, but when I try and run predict I get an error message:

```
predict(procellminvar.rf, procelldd)
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'subpop' not found
```

I don't understand why. Could anybody explain to me in simple terms what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: R is probably telling you that `procelldd` has no variable called `subpop`. Your new data frame has to have every single variable that was used in your original rf call. (In this case, everything in `procell6.imputed`.)

Comment: Thanks. All the variables in the new data frame are the same, the only difference is the data. In procell6.imputed I specify variables 6:80, but obviously I haven't for the new data - this wouldn't have an impact would it? If so how would I resolve it?

Comment: The variable subpop is not in procelldd. That is the problem.

Comment: Ok, so I see what's happened - all of the variables that have no data within the columns aren't there, so procelldd now has 73 rather than 80 variables. The data isn't there because they're data deficient species though. Is there a way to prevent these columns from getting dropped when the data is read in to R? Or will they have to have a value in them (I'm not sure I'd get around it if that is the case).

Comment: It wouldn't matter in this case anyway. randomForest won't generate predictions if some of the variables needed are missing (i.e. NA). You either need a different model, or different data (imputed, different subset,...), or both.

Comment: I don't think I can use imputation because the response variable has missing data (at least I can't do it the way I have above). To test, I've put 0's in all of the columns with no data - obviously I can't really do this as it's not 'real' data but I just wanted to see what happens - and it's come back with an output: all four cases in class 0, levels given as 0 1 2 3 4 which equates to my response variable. Having not managed to make the predict function work I'm presuming that this is what the output should be like if it had worked properly?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're running the predict on the full dataset but you are not using the full dataset in the training. Nor are you using the original variables. So you need to make sure that each variable you are using in the training also is present in the test data.